# IBM MQ listener service - onMessage not getting triggered

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I want to read messages from IBM MQ and just print them.

//my main class

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class QueueConnector {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory qcf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        MQQueueConnection qc;
        Queue queue;
        MQQueueSession queueSession;
        MessageConsumer consumer;
        qcf.setHostName ("XYZ");
        qcf.setPort (Integer.parseInt("abc"));
        qcf.setQueueManager ("ABC");
        qcf.setChannel ("IJK");
        qcf.setTransportType (WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        qc = (MQQueueConnection) qcf.createQueueConnection ();
        queue = new MQQueue("QUEUE_NAME");
        queueSession = (MQQueueSession) qc.createQueueSession (false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue);
        Listener listener = new Listener();
        consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
        qc.start();
    }
}
```

// listener class

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class Listener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            System.out.println(((TextMessage)message).getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("From Listener!");

    }
}
```

The main class is getting terminated without calling onMessage, even if there are messages in queue. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: I voted to have this question reopened and to close the new question you opened as a duplicate.   You should not open duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep your program running. When you reach the end of main - the program will exit and hence your listener won't fire.

Try placing `new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();` at the end of your method to verify that it works. Of course, you may want to change this exit condition to something more appropriate (or actually close the scanner).

Comment: What would be the ideal approach to keep the program running in production if the requirement is just to read message from queue and print it. Why should we place scanner code. ?  Any other better solution?

Comment: can u suggest any other appoach to keep the program not to exit? Scanner code seems not a good approach in production

Comment: @Stunner Have you found a better way?