# IBM MQ JMS java listener code keeping the program running

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

This question is in continuation to the question asked 
[IBM MQ listener service - onMessage not getting triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654451/ibm-mq-listener-service-onmessage-not-getting-triggered?rq=1)

Let's say the same code is in production , now how do we keep the program running.  I felt adding scanner code is not the correct or effective way of achieving it.  Is there any better solution to keep the program running so when the end of main is reached , program will not quit.  Ideally i think the call to start method `qc.start()` should wait indefinitely. 
Please let me know how do we implement this in a proper and ideal way.

Requirement is the listener should run indefinitely waiting for new messages.  I do not have any other business condition to put in the main method inorder to keep the program running. Adding scanner code doesn't seem a good approach.  What's the ideal way ??

Answer (score 2):

What I think what you are asking is how to keep a Java program running indefinitely.

There are several ways, but you do need a way of terminating it, either by user interrupt or a signal, and you don't want it in a tight loop so it will consume all CPU and stack memory, leaving nothing for your `onMessage` event.

You don't want to put to sleep the `onMessage` so it should be spawned in a secondary thread, allowing the main thread to periodically awaken from a sleep to check for a
termination signal.

The basics are

```java
Thread worker = new Thread(new yourOnMessageThread());
worker.start();

while(true) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(sleep duration);
  } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    // check for termination signal
    // if required, terminate
  }
}
```

Comment: in my case yourOnMessageThread()  object class doesn't extends thread or implements Runnable.. i did not get your code snippet. and can u elaborate,,,

Comment: In which case you will need to make it so. The code that sets up and waits for onMessage will need to be in the secondary thread. If you are now asking ‘how to I launch secondary worker threads in java’, then I think that question has already been asked and answered in Stack.

Comment: is Thread.sleep the only solution ??  Why do I even should call sleep method to make by program running. No other ideal solution? Infact calling scanner.next() is better than sleep.. I still think there might be some better way to acheive it ...

Answer (score 1):

Please note that JMS comes with 2 methods of message dispatching: Synchronous vs. Asynchronous. For starters, and if your program doesn't have to do *anything unless there is a new message*, try out **synchronous dispatching** first. You don't need to create and set a Listener object:

```
  consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue); 
  qc.start();
  while( nummsgs<maxmsgs || maxmsgs==0 ) {

    Message message = consumer.receive(1000); // receive the next message or wait up to 1 second, for example
    if (message != null) {

      nummsgs++;
      ... processing code ...
    }
 }
```

(I usually like to make the while's end condition based on an input parameter like `int maxmsgs = 0;` so you can automatically stop after processing 100000 messages, e.g. for performance testing, or just specify 0 to keep it running forever).

There's nothing wrong with this approach and because the code is simpler to write and understand, I would recommend it as a first-level approach. The main loop is simply the MQ-dispatcher loop which makes sense if that's the main purpose of your program.

If your program does many things, one of which is MQ receiving, **asynchronous dispatching** might be better. The main loop does not have an 'MQ focus' anymore. It just sits there and waits until someone presses Ctrl-C or kills the program.

```
  consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue);
  Listener listener = new Listener();
  consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
  qc.start();

  Object waitLock = new Object();
  while( nummsgs<maxmsgs || maxmsgs==0 ) {

    synchronized(waitLock) {
      waitLock.wait(1000); // wait up to 1 second, for example
    }
  }
```

Comment: I woud like to go for asynchronous dispatching.. but the thing is i do not want to use sleep.... Any other ideal solution??

Comment: well, your main thread needs to do 'something'. And if you don't stop it it will run to the end and finish your program. A nicer alternative to Thread.sleep is Object.wait()

Comment: After some time i am getting Interrupted exception though no one on the earth is calling notify or notifyall :).   For now I am proceeding with scanner.next as it it is assured that the program keeps running forever when launched in background in prod.  Upvoted your answer.. Thank u

Comment: What is safer than waiting on the main object is to create an extra Object for it: declare Object waitLock = new Object(); and then inside the while-loop:  synchronized { waitLock.wait(1000); }

Comment: Nope. Java wait() is ultimately calling pthread Linux API (if you are on Linux) which implements even handling natively. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265523/how-is-java-wait-waiting-implemented but also just try it out and watch your CPU usage.